# How to show strategy.position_avg_price in text box in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using one tradingview strategy and I am using pyramid orders for long until i got sell order with at least 1% profit.

Let us say I have a 1 st long order I am thinking to sell that If I got 1% or more profit on sell order.

If sell order comes again without meeting the above condition then I wait for 2nd buy order like so on up to 5 orders.

1st order : Quentity : 1 Price:100

2nd order : Quantity : 1 Price:90

3rd order : Quantity : 1 Price:80

4th Order : Quantity : 1 Price:70

5th Order : Quantity : 1 Price:60

Total Orders:5 Total Price:400 Average Price:80

Now I wanted to show average price in a box in tradingview using pine script.

How to do that.
I can able to show that average price in line but that shrinks the view when there is a lot of fall in the market.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table for that.

```
var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
str_pos_size = str.tostring(strategy.position_avg_price)
table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = str_pos_size)
```